# How to limit wechat asset picker to only JPG imges

Tags: flutter

In my app I want to allow users to pick multiple photos, I am usin for this Wechat Asset Picker, as I need to put a limit nfor number of photos can be selected.
afer that I need to compress these photos to reduce their siz befor uploadting to firestore.

I have two problems:
first, we chat asset picker package show all assets on the device, images, videos, etc. while I need to alow user only to upload images.

second, I am using Flutter Image Compress package for compressing, which works only with JPG.

Is there any better packages for my objective?
if not, my questions is how to limit wechat asset picker to only jpg images?

snapshots of code:

```
 final List<myimagepicker.AssetEntity>? result =
                  await myimagepicker.AssetPicker.pickAssets(
                context,
                pickerConfig: const myimagepicker.AssetPickerConfig(
                  gridCount: 3,
                  maxAssets: 10,
                  pickerTheme: null,
                  themeColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 91, 165),
                  pageSize: 30,            
                ),

 var result = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
      imageslist[i].absolute.path,
      outPath,
      quality: 50,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultList = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(
  context,
  pickerConfig: const AssetPickerConfig(
    maxAssets: 3,
    requestType: RequestType.image, ✅
  ),
```

only jpg?
don't know
but only image?
you can set requestType.

Comment: This limit it to images, but not speific image extensions, I want to use only JPG if possible.